Unexpected TypeScript behavior with oxide.ts
To fully reproduce the issue, you could set up tiny Node.js project using the following code:
package.json:
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && node app.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "22.5.4",
    "typescript": "5.5.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "oxide.ts": "1.1.0"
  }
}

tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  }
}

app.ts:
import { None, Option } from 'oxide.ts'

export enum Currency {
  EUR = 'EUR',
  UAH = 'UAH',
  USD = 'USD',
}

export interface GenericClientInterface {
  execute(address: string): Promise<void>
}

export interface SpecificClientInterface extends GenericClientInterface {
  lookup(account: string): Promise<boolean>
}

export type CurrencyClientMap = {
  [Currency.EUR]: Option<GenericClientInterface>
  [Currency.UAH]: Option<SpecificClientInterface>
  [Currency.USD]: typeof None
}

export interface CurrencyFactoryInterface {
  build<C extends Currency>(currency: C): CurrencyClientMap[C]
}

export class MyClass{
  public constructor(
    private readonly currencyClientFactory: CurrencyFactoryInterface,
  ) {}

  public execute(currency: Currency): void {
    const clientResult = this.currencyClientFactory.build(currency)

    if (clientResult.isNone()) { // <-- TypeScript error here.
      console.log('clientResult is None')
    }

    const client = clientResult.unwrap()

    console.log('Client: ', client)
  }
}

If you set up a project the way described above, you'll notice that in line 35 of app.ts, there is a TypeScript error:
The 'this' context of type 'Option<GenericClientInterface> | Option<SpecificClientInterface> | Readonly<OptionType<never>>' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Option<GenericClientInterface> & Option<SpecificClientInterface> & Option<never>'.
  Type 'Option<GenericClientInterface>' is not assignable to type 'Option<GenericClientInterface> & Option<SpecificClientInterface> & Option<never>'.ts(2684)

Why is it happening? All three returned types have .isNone() method. Why A | B | C is expected to be A & B & C in the value returned by .build() method? Is it a TypeScript or Oxide.ts issue?

This is oxisde specific. With my simpler Option type it works fine: https://tsplay.dev/WGgDXW

The issue is in oxide types.
Oxide is Rust's Option and Result<T, E>, implemented for TypeScript, unfortunately it does not play nice with TS type system.
Let's look at the definitions
export const T = Symbol("T");
export const Val = Symbol("Val")
export type Option<T> = OptionType<T>;
class OptionType<T> {
   readonly [T]: boolean;
   readonly [Val]: T;

   constructor(val: T, some: boolean) {
      this[T] = some;
      this[Val] = val;
   }

   isSome(this: Option<T>): this is Some<T> {
      return this[T];
   }

   isNone(this: Option<T>): this is None {
      return !this[T];
   }
}
export type Some<T> = OptionType<T> & { [T]: true };
export type None = OptionType<never> & { [T]: false };
export const None = Object.freeze(
   new OptionType<never>(undefined as never, false)
);

Firsty, does not take full advantage of TS union types and defines None as OptionType<never>. Option as an union of Some and None is much cleaner solution in TS.
Secondly, it defines OptionType as class and uses it as a this parameter. Unfortunately it breaks if it is called on a variable which is an union of different types.
isNone(this: Option<T>): this is None {
    return !this[T];
}

In call
const clientResult = this.currencyClientFactory.build(currency);


clientResult has type  None | Option<GenericClientInterface> | Option<SpecificClientInterface>.
When calling clientResult.isNone() TS needs to infer the type of this. Thus it transforms the union to intersection: Option<never> & Option<GenericClientInterface> & Option<SpecificClientInterface>. Unfortunately never is not assignable to anything, so TS complains.

For the call to work, it should be defined as:
isNone(this: Option<T>): this is None {
  return !this[T];
}

Given the knowledge above, you can:
Option 0: reconsider using this library
Option 1: submit a pull request
Option 2: work around these issues
function isNone<T>(o: Option<T>) {
  return o.isNone();
}

function unwrap<T>(o: Option<T>): T {
  return o.unwrap();
}

export class MyClass{
  public constructor(
    private readonly currencyClientFactory: CurrencyFactoryInterface,
  ) {}

  public execute(currency: Currency): void {
    const clientResult = this.currencyClientFactory.build(currency)

    // Now it works
    if (isNone(clientResult)) {
      console.log('clientResult is None')
    } else {
      // Now it works
      const client = unwrap(clientResult);
      console.log('Client: ', client)
    }
  }
}

Code on TS Playground

Unfortunately abandoning Oxide is not an option as it is vastly adopted in my project. I've created an issue on GitHub, so maybe one day somebody or me, when I have time, will take a look on the matter. Meanwhile I'll stub types until better solution comes. Thanks!
